# How can we assign one of the pod's of StatefulSet to a specific node of a Kubernetes cluster in pod affinity / antiaffinity

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a 7 node cluster. I have an app 'A' having 3 replicas running in random 3 nodes. I have another app 'B' having 5 replicas, now I have to assign only 1 of the replicas of 'B' to the same node as 'A'. Other 4 replicas can run in different nodes.

```
Node 1  -   A1
Node 2  -   B2
Node 3  -   B3
Node 4  -   A2, B1
Node 5  -   B4
Node 6  -   A3
Node 7  -   B5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Affinity Rule 1: Same type of pods will push each other
- Affinity Rule 2: Different type of pods will attract each other

By those rules, you can achieve something like bellow:

```
Node 1: A1, B1
Node 2: A2, B2
Node 3: A3, B3
Node 4: B4
Node 5: B5
... ...
```

But if you add taint to Node:1,2 such that no B pods will be able to be scheduled on those nodes. And add taint to Node:4,5,6,7 such that no A will be able to be scheduled on those nodes.

Then you will end up having the following distribution:

```
Node 1  -   A1
Node 2  -   A2
Node 3  -   A3, B1
Node 4  -   B2
Node 5  -   B3
Node 6  -   B4
Node 7  -   B5
```

Comment: That's a useful idea. Will try that, however is it possible to achieve this only from the POD side, with restricting at node level N1 and N2 not having B, movement of pods will become restricted.